# Azure Service Fabric - possible to have multiple Node Types with one public IP address?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

In Azure Service Fabric, is it possible to have multiple node types with single public IP address?

It is not supported by the portal, and I have spent all day playing with the ARM template and so far no luck.

Looks like it boils down to being able to have two load balancers point to the same public IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, you can only associate a public IP to a single load balancer and this makes sense, as how would a request be routed to a specific LB. That being said depending on what your are trying to achieve I would say your choices are:

1. Two public IPs and as each node type gets its own vnet and LB this shouldn't be a problem.
2. A single node type
3. Keep your two node types but treat one node type like your DMZ, with your public IP and then the second like your internal network, potentially with your state for additional separation and security.

Comment: That seems to be the case, looks like if it is really needed, #3 is the way to go. Fortunately in my case, it appears I can live with two public IPs - so I'm going with #1. Thanks!